# How to manage adding Event Listeners to several similar elements

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm struggling with adjusting .paragraph(s) (which have value of 'display: none'). I added event listener to .holder__question and ended up adding 'display: block' to .slider's elements on click. But I wanted only .paragraph to change its value.
ps. It's just a snippet, I have 5 '.holder__question' boxes.

```
              <div class="holder__question">

                   <div class="slider">
                      <h3>Querstion?</h3>
                      <img class="turn" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow">
                   </div>

                      <div class="paragraph">
                         <p>...Smth...</p>
                      </div>
           </div>


const questions = document.querySelectorAll('h3')
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('img')
const hidden = document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph')
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.holder__question')



sliders.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', e => {
                if(e.target.style.display = "none"){
                        e.target.style.display = "block"
                }
        })
      })
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the issue is.

Comment: Because you have your event listener on the parent element, you need to check what element you are clicking.  Something like "if target has class paragraph, do something".
You also have a single = sign in your if statement.. that should be ===

Comment: "holder__question" is a parent element and "slider" & "paragraph" are children. I thought that bubble effect will check the condition and catch up to "paragraph". Instead whatever I tweak the function it works only for "slider" or does nothin =(